# Returning reference and manipulating specific variable in PHP multidimensional array

Tags: php

I'm trying to return a reference from a specific position in a multidimensional global array and then manipulate it ... it's a deep nested array.

I'm trying to avoid having to iterate the array in every function that needs to manipulate a specific part.

I've tried all matter of this:

```
$foo = &get('bar');

$foo['something'] = 'for nothing';
 
var_dump($array); // unaffected

function &get($search) {
    global $array;
    foreach(...) {
        foreach(...) {
            foreach(... as $key => &val) {
               if($val === $search) return &val;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This may not even be possible in PHP, but hoping I'm wrong and just missing something obvious.

Also, not married to a multidimensional array if there is an easier way to store and manipulate complex objects, it just needs to be as fast as possible.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: You need to use references for the iteration variables in each `foreach`. Otherwise you get a copy in the nested loop, and you're returning a reference to the copy.

Comment: `let` is not PHP syntax.

Comment: `$foo['something'] = 'for nothing';` implies that `$foo` is an array. But `return $val;` is returning the value, which is the string `'bar'`. What are you really expecting to do? Should that have been `$foo = 'for nothing'`?

Comment: Please post a [mre] and show what you expect the result to be. And fix all your syntax errors -- you're mixing PHP and JavaScript syntax.

Comment: Oops, sorry for the "let" and my variable cross contamination with JS was just an oversight, long day bouncing around languages.  Also, embarrassed to post the full example, it's code I'm not allowed to share and frankly a bit insane.  I tried, poorly, to outline it as best and minimal I could.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed the syntax errors.

You need to use references for the iteration variables in all the `foreach` loops.

You don't need to use `&` when you're returning `$val`, just `return $val;`.

To update, you should just assign directly to `$foo`, since it doesn't contain an array.

```
<?php
$array = [[["foo", "bar"]]];
$foo = &get('bar');

$foo = 'for nothing';

var_dump($array);

function &get($search) {
    global $array;
    foreach($array as &$level1) {
        foreach($level1 as &$level2) {
            foreach($level2 as &$val) {
               if($val === $search) return $val;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(3) "foo"
      [1]=>
      &string(11) "for nothing"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That clicked! Thank you! Finally, I get how to pass around refs in PHP!